# How to remove special character in yaml file

Tags: yaml, datadog

Yaml file details.

```yaml
- server: 1.2.1.4  
  port: 443   
  transport: TCP    
  server_hostname: *.abc.com
```

we have one server with *.abc.com but when I used try use with same server it is not allowing.
Error : "did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character"

so I have try to escape * with * or \* but Datadog server it showing _.adc.com

but I want to use in YAML to Datadog  like same *.abc.com

please can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

A `*` starts a YAML alias. To avoid this, quote the scalar:

```yaml
- server: 1.2.1.4  
  port: 443   
  transport: TCP    
  server_hostname: "*.abc.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for response , But we I tried to use double quote for "*.abc.com"  it is taking in datadog server as a '_.abc.com' and still it is not working